# why should i use docker image "confluentinc/kafka" to kafka cluster?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform, kafka-cluster

I did

```
docker-compose up
```

for kafka clustering in my local.

and whenever i want to make topic, retrieve topics i have or search data stored in the topic i use

```
docker run --net=host --rm confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest kafka-topics --describe --topic bar --zookeeper localhost:32181
```

which is on the official kafka clustering deployment site.

However i really want to use Kafka in my local storage not the kafka docker image like

```
kafka-topics --describe --topic bar --zookeeper localhost:32181
```

if i use the code above i face this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:258)
```

Besides if i check **netstat -anp tcp**
there is no LISTEN ports from kafka cluster.

What am i supposed to do ?
and please let me know what i am missing now about docker (because i am really new to docker :( )

**This is yaml configuration**

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 22181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: localhost:22888:23888;localhost:32888:33888;localhost:42888:43888
    network_mode: host
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"

  zookeeper-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: localhost:22888:23888;localhost:32888:33888;localhost:42888:43888
    network_mode: host
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"

  zookeeper-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 42181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: localhost:22888:23888;localhost:32888:33888;localhost:42888:43888
    network_mode: host
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"

  kafka-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: localhost:22181,localhost:32181,localhost:42181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:19092
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"

  kafka-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    network_mode: host
"docker-compose.yml" 83L, 2321C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Kafka (and Zookeeper) on your host, then, no, you don't need Docker at all.

You should not use `localhost` in any connection string from the container, rather use the external service names of the containers and remove `network_mode` from the configurations.

Note: multiple brokers/zookeepers on one machine isn't helping anything.

> or search data stored in the topic

You shouldn't use zookeeper to do that

Comment: Using the external service names of the containers and removing network_mode exactly working for me. 
Thanks a lot :)
I understand the note which is explaining multiple brokers/zookeepers on one machine isn't helping anything, after testing docker kafka clustering in my local then i will divide those containers to each AWS machine. Thanks :)

Comment: If running Docker on AWS, you might as well just use Kubernetes Helm Charts. If you don't want to manage that, just use MSK, Confluent Cloud, or other hosted Kafka

Comment: what if i just use AWS as an each one docker container host without Kubernetes. Do you think Kafka is still possibly working with ?

Comment: That's exactly what the hosted offerings provide. Kafka works better outside a container, in my opinion